# В чем разница и какие недостатки (если они есть) у такой записи в прототип?

Tags: javascript

В чем разница между двумя этими видами записи и какие у второго подхода недостатки перед первым? Почему все советуют первый вариант, когда второй в десять раз быстрее?

```
var REPEAT = 5;
var ITERATION = 10000000;

function runTest(){
    while(REPEAT-- > 0)
    {
        console.log(speed());
    }
    return;
}

function A( ){}
A.prototype = { run: function( ){}};

function B( ){}
B.prototype.run = function( ){};

var a = new A( ); // 260
var b = new B( ); // 25

function speed(){

    var startTime = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < ITERATION; i++) {
        b.run( );
    };

    var finishTime = new Date();
    return 'Время выполнения - ' + (finishTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) + '.' 
}

runTest();
```

Comment: > когда второй в десять раз быстрее

У вас в программе прототип задается от 100 000 раз, чтобы об этом заботиться?

Comment: Дело не в создании прототипа, а в том, что если я буду обращаться к методу a или b, то между ними будет разница в десять раз. Понимаете? Особо разницы между подходами создания никакой, а разница обращения к свойствам и методам в десять раз. И я понимаю, почему нет нормальных игр на html5 + js, их, наверное, делают те, кто не учился обращать внимание на мелочи, и в конечном итоге есть то, что есть.

Вот я и хочу узнать, есть ли какая-то фатальная разница в отсутствии сущности во втором варианте?

Comment: @vas, а откуда такие данные по разности скорости выполнения и о том, что они существенно влияют на производительность. Насколько я понимаю, этот скрипт отработает всего один раз при инициализации функций в прототип и остальные вызовы уже никак с ним не будут связаны.

--------

Кстати по поводу игр - тут основная проблема в рендеринге графики, а не алгоритмах. Когда у меня летают миллионные итерации кода, но графика не может выдержать более двух тысяч активных экранных объектов, это печально.

Comment: Данные я пока только в nodejs замерял, а в онлайн сервисе начал впервые делать и после немного переделывания меня как спамера погнали с него.

Comment: Померил здесь http://jsperf.com/create-prototype если сделал правильно ( если кто-то будет смотреть, то посмотрите на правильность самого теста, я впервые так делаю ), то показывает одинаковую скорость. Но странно, почему у nodejs такая разница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, давайте разберем механизм работы JavaScript на простом примере.

Создадим наши два объекта, использую консоль браузера хром.

```
function a(){}
a.prototype = {
    a : function(){},
    b : function(){}
}

function b(){}
b.prototype.a = function(){}
b.prototype.b = function(){}
```

После этого выполним дамп их прототипов, получим такой результат:

```
› a.prototype
▼ Object {a: function, b: function}
    ► a: function (){}
    ► b: function (){}
    ► __proto__: Object

› b.prototype
▼ b {a: function, b: function}
   ► a: function (){}
   ► b: function (){}
   ► constructor: function b(){}
   ► __proto__: Object
```

Единственное различие между двумя объектами - это наличие свойства constructor со ссылкой на саму функцию. В общем-то это легко поправить:

```
function a(){}
a.prototype = {
    a : function(){},
    b : function(){},
    constructor: a
}

› a.prototype
▼ a {a: function, b: function}
   ► a: function (){}
   ► b: function (){}
   ► constructor: function a(){}
   ► __proto__: Object
```

То есть результат в обоих случаях будет совершенно одинаковый, за исключением свойства constructor, который в данном случае не влияет на производительность вызова других функций и его можно легко добавить. Почему nodejs у Вас так себя повел, я не знаю, но скорее всего дело в элементарной погрешности.

Что же касается рекомендуемого кода:

```
function a(){}
a.prototype = {
    a : function(){},
    b : function(){}
}
```

Он, с точки зрения проектирования, намного нагляднее разбросанных по файлу определения новых полей, поскольку они аккуратно сгруппированы в одном месте.

P.S. По поводу теста - 30 итераций не дают никакого результата, надо было ставить несколько сотен тысяч и какой-нибудь простой код внутрь функций.

Comment: Я добавил код теста, который, как я уже сказал, я выполнял при помощи nodejs. И скорость такая, как указана в примере.